# How can you preselect rel_list value TinyMCE 5?

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-4, tinymce-5

I want to make the `noreferrer noopener value` preselected in `rel_list` instead of `noopener`.

There is some kind of order I guess in which the plugin selects the default value.

Tried adding a number, start alphabetically the title, but I always get the `noopener` value preselected.

```
rel_list: [
  {title: 'noopener', value: 'noopener'},
  {title: 'nofollow noreferrer noopener', value: 'nofollow noreferrer noopener'}
],
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I declare options to be set as default **default_link_target** in and someway its work for link plagin too.

```
    default_link_target: [
        'nofollow'
    ],

    rel_list: [
        {title: 'No Follow', value: 'nofollow'},
        {title: 'Disable', value: ''}
    ],
```

In this snippet always set to **No Follow** and without **default_link_target** always set to **Disable**

https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/plugins/opensource/link/#default_link_target

It feels more like hack, not real solution